# Check the records which are not in the subquery DB2

Tags: join, db2

I have a scenario in which I have to count all those IDs which are not included in my table.

1. I have a source(consists on 3 tables).
2. I select records from source into my table. (used LEFT OUTER JOIN)

What I want to do is this...

```
SELECT *
FROM SOURCE_SYSTEM
WHERE ID NOT IN (my query which brings data initially from the source_system)
```

SOURCE_SYSTEM = My three source tables.

Please guide how I can write my query to figure out all those IDs which don't come into my table from the source_system.

Comment: Not clear. You pull data from 3 "source tables" into "your table". After this, is it that you want to repeat the process, but only bring in data that you have not brought in before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  source_system ss
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM other_table ot WHERE ss.id=ot.id)
```